# assign the same value to multiple variables

Tags: r

I wish to assign the same value to multiple variables in a `data.frame`.  I have looked at multiple posts here that seem similar, but do not appear to address my specific problem.

[Mass variable declaration and assignment in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384593/mass-variable-declaration-and-assignment-in-r)

[Assign multiple new variables on LHS in a single line in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-on-lhs-in-a-single-line-in-r)

Here is an example `data.frame` I would like to create:

```
data = data.frame(
  a1 =  0.614, a2 =  0.614, a3 =  0.614, a4 =  0.614, a5  =  0.614,
  a6 =  0.614, a7 =  0.614, a8 =  0.614, a9 =  0.614, a10 =  0.614,
  c1 = -6.198, c2 = -6.198, c3 = -6.198, c4 = -6.198, c5  = -6.198,
  c6 = -6.198, c7 = -6.198, c8 = -6.198, c9 = -6.198, c10 = -6.198,
  d1 = 35.952, d2 = 35.952, d3 = 35.952, d4 = 35.952, d5  = 35.952,
  d6 = 35.952, d7 = 35.952, d8 = 35.952, d9 = 35.952, d10 = 35.952)
```

Thank you for any advice or assistance.  I prefer a solution in base `R`.  Sorry if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about (insert as many `row.names` as you want rows in the output `data.frame`):

```
data = data.frame(row.names = '1')
data[paste0('a', 1:10)] = .614
data[paste0('c', 1:10)] = -6.198
data[paste0('d', 1:10)] = 35.952
```

Or (column names won't be exactly right; thanks @Frank for simplifying my approach here)

```
data.frame(a = .641, c = -6.198, d = 35.052)[ , rep(1:3, each = 10)]
```

Comment: Both answers are really nice.  I usually wait 24+ hours to accept, but thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Do it all in one go:

```
n <- 10
setNames(
  data.frame(rep(list(0.641,-6.198,35.952), each=n)),
  paste0(rep(c("a","c","d"),each=n), seq_len(n))
)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how to adjust this if we want more than one row in the output `data.frame` (scratch that, nvm, just have to declare the `list` correctly.)

Comment: @MichaelChirico - just bung `[rep(1,nrows),]` on the end.

Comment: nice, I had in mine a case of e.g. repeating `c(.641, .58)` in a given column many times, but both are pretty easy to fit into this approach