# Recode multiple polytomous variables

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, recode

This question is about recoding of polytomous variables in a large data set. As the data is large and recoding is to be done on many variables, I am looking for a more flexible way to call all the relevant variables and perform the recoding. There are many resolved issues about recoding (e.g. [Recoding multiple variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836503/recoding-multiple-variables-in-r)), but these do not fit into the specifics of this question. Below is an example of the data:

```
df<-data.frame("id"=c(1:5),
           "ax1"=c(2,1,4,3,4),
           "ax2"=c(7,3,6,2,2),
           "bx1"=c(3,5,7,1,2),
           "bx2"=c(1,3,1,5,2),
           "cx1"=c(1,1,7,1,6),
           "cx2"=c(3,9,5,5,4))
```

For instance, I would like to recode `ax1`, `bx1` and `cx1`. On these variables, I want to recode 1, 2, 3, 4 as 0, 1, 1, 0, respectively and recode as `NA` otherwise. With the use of the 'dplyr' package I tried

```
df <- df %>%  
 mutate_at( vars(ends_with("x1")),
         list(~ ifelse( . == 1, 0, ifelse(.== 2, 1, ifelse(.==3, 1, ifelse(.==4, 0,NA))))))
```

However, this does not produce the expected output. The expected output would look like

```
   id ax1 ax2 bx1 bx2 cx1 cx2
1  1   1   7   1   1   0   3
2  2   0   3  NA   3   0   9
3  3   0   6  NA   1  NA   5
4  4   1   2   0   5   0   5
5  5   0   2   1   2  NA   4
```

Comment: ?? I get the correct result when I run your code (as long as I add a missing close-parenthesis at the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr`, there is a `recode` function specifically for this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
   mutate_at(vars(ends_with("x1")),
        ~recode(., `1` = 0, `2` = 1, `3` = 1, `4` = 0, .default = NA_real_)))

#  id ax1 ax2 bx1 bx2 cx1 cx2
#1  1   1   7   1   1   0   3
#2  2   0   3  NA   3   0   9
#3  3   0   6  NA   1  NA   5
#4  4   1   2   0   5   0   5
#5  5   0   2   1   2  NA   4
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(ends_with("x1")), 
    ~case_when(. %in% c(1,4) ~ 0,
               . %in% c(2,3) ~ 1))
```

(Not sure why you need the `list()` in there?)